# Architecture Implementation and Design for a Notification System using socket.io node.js and incoming messages

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, comet, socket.io

Disclaimers

- I have not worked with node.js before
- I have not used socket.io before

I'm looking at implementing a Google Plus, Facebook, StackOverflow style notification system. I'm not an inexperienced developer, and eventually I will figure this out, but I'm just looking for a thrust to the right direction.

What I want is for users who are browsing my site to be notified during their browsing session when they receive a new message.

Currently, all of my messages are stored in a single table.

```
  |  id    | messageSubject   | messageBody     | hasRead   | readDate   | sentDate   | sentToUser  | sentFromUser  |
  |   1    |   HelloWorld     | Nada            |   0       | `null`     | `null      |      1      |      10       |
```

Now, all of my messages are retrieved from **dozens** of different sources.

- A message can be entered via an API by third parties
- Message are pulled from Send Grid
- Messages can be sent via private message Controllers.
- Etc etc

What I want is to have a way to be able to notify users when a new message is received. I'm happy to refactor my code any way which makes it possible to notify my node.js when I receive a insert a message if that is what I need to do.

But I am just not quite sure where to start.

My problem is that all of my messages are entered into mysql through dozens of different sources, my `Insert` statements are in a lot of areas. So I just don't know the best way to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to look at presentation [Why databases suck for messaging](http://www.slideshare.net/rabbitmq/why-databases-suck-for-messaging) which is namely about why you shouldn't use databases such as MySQL for messaging. [Messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messaging_pattern) and notifications systems works well with [Event Driven Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) and I would recommend to watch [this](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Events-Are-Not-Just-for-Notifications) presentation or to learn more on this topic from [here](http://www.infoq.com/eventdrivenarchitecture/) in order to get a bigger picture about event driven "ecosystem".

Comment: what if the links get expired?