# What database/technology to use for a notification system on a node.js site?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, notifications

I'm looking to implement notifications within my node.js application. I currently use mysql for relational data (users, submissions, comments, etc). I use mongodb for page views only.

To build a notification system, does it make more sense (from a performance standpoint) to use mongodb vs MySQL?

Also, what's the convention for showing new notifications to users? At first, I was thinking that I'd have a notification icon, and they click on it and it does an ajax call to look for all new notifications from the user, but I want to show the user that the icon is actually worth clicking (either with some different color or a bubble with the number of new notifications like Google Plus does).

I could do it when the user logs it, but that would mean the user would only see new notifications when they logged out and back in (because it'd be saved in their session). Should I poll for updates? I'm not sure if that's the recommended method as it seems like overkill to show a single digit (or more depending on the num of notifications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using node then you can 'push' notifications to a connected user via [websockets](http://socket.io/docs/). The linked document is an example of one well known websocket engine that has good performance and good documentation. That way your application can send notifications to any user, or sets of users, or everyone based on simple queries that you setup.

Data storage is a different question. Generally mysql does have poor perfomance in cases of high scalability, and mongo does generally have a quicker read query response, but it depends on what data structure you wish to use. If your data is in a simple key-value structure with no real need for relational data, then perhaps using a memory store such as [Redis](http://redis.io/) would be the most suitable.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7186747/1495728) answer has more information on your question too if you want to follow up and investigate more.

Comment: Perfect I'll go with socket.io and mongo. Thanks!